# Implementing Service in Android

Tags: android

Scenario : Uploading a list of files to the server.

- There are two servers , one file server & one application webserver.
- A token is provided by the application server having a time-out : 5 mins
- When a file is being uploaded to the file server, another request needs to be made simultaneously every 5 mins to the application server, so the token doesn't get expired.

Currently I am implementing the file upload using an AsyncTask. In order to create another request for the token, what should be my approach?

Should I run a Service which sends a request every 5 mins to the application server?

I need to also handle the Call interrupting scenario(paused state) , when the request for token should continue its operation.

Any hints/suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second AsyncTask for retrieving the tokenevery five minutes. Service or not, it's your choice.

Typically, if the upload process for your app takes too long to complete, it's always a good idea to do it through a service.

Answer (score 0):

The best method (imo) would be:

1. A service which manages the files uploading to the file server.
2. A broadcast receiver which retrieves the token.

Now, when the uploading begins and you need the tokens, schedule an alarm for the current time (so it is executed immediately) and the alarm should start the boardcastreceiver.

Then, while in the broadcast receiver `onReceive` method, you should check whats up with the service. If its still running (still uploading files) you should re schedule an alarm that will be fired in 5 minutes.

When the alarm is fired - before the broadcast receiver is getting another token, you should make sure it is still needed.

AsyncTask is not a good idea, because I am almost sure it **dies** when your activity is destroyed. And you don't want to make the user wait so much time untill the files are uploaded, are you?

Answer (score 0):

Simply start your upload by checking the age of your token. Retrieve the token in the same thread as your file upload, before sending it, to make sure your token is valid.